# SetProgress calls setLevel for progress bar

Tags: android

I have a question about how the android default progress bar work. When you call the method setProgress(), does it basically call setLevel on a Clip drawable for progress bar?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It calls `setLevel` on any drawable actually](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress%28int%2Cfloat%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29). There's no restriction in the API for what kind of Drawable you set for the indeterminate or determinant drawable, so it can be anything.

It does some other things too.  Most notably, a `ProgressBar` will actually post the drawing operation on the UI thread so you can call `setProgress` on a worker thread. It also handles animations and other drawing operations.

Comment: Thank you :) trying to understand progress bar operation